# Exception calling InvokeSet, The directory property cannot be found in the cache

Tags: powershell, ldap, adsi

When running the below code I receive the error
`Exception calling "InvokeSet" with "2" argument(s): "The directory property cannot be found in the cache."` Online this error exists because of an issue with a variable being null. After using Write-Host I have come to the conclusion that the `$User = [ADSI]$LdapUser` line is the one causing an issue.

```
#Set Remote Control Settings Permissions 
        $LdapUser = "LDAP://" + (Get-ADUser $username).distinguishedName
        Write-Host $LdapUser
        $User = [ADSI]$LdapUser
        Write-Host $User
        $User.InvokeSet("EnableRemoteControl",5)
        $User.InvokeSet("TerminalServicesHomeDrive","U:\")
        $User.setinfo()
```

The Write-Host command for `$LdapUser` displays `"LDAP://CN=Test Taco,CN=Users,DC=blah,DC=org"` which is correct however the Write-Host Command for `$User` displays `System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry` 
Why does the `$User` variable display the wrong information and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with my code was that I was using the number 5 for enable remote control as well as using U:\ the correct code uses a 2 as well as no backslash so U:

```
#Set Remote Control Settings Permissions 
        $LdapUser = "LDAP://" + (Get-ADUser $username).distinguishedName
        $User = [ADSI]$LdapUser
        Write-Host $User
        $User.InvokeSet("EnableRemoteControl",2)
        $User.InvokeSet("TerminalServicesHomeDrive","U:")
        $User.setinfo()

pause
```

Thank you @Judd Davey for helping me through his answer to realize where I could be going wrong in my answer. I am not quite certain why it gave me such a weird error.

Answer (score 1):

`write-host` can only accept a string of text.

`$User` is not a string, its more like an array, as it contains two lines of information. It contains the "distinguishedName" and the "Path".

You can type:

```
Write-Host $User.path
Write-Host $User.distinguishedName
```

The issue is this this command:

```
$User.InvokeSet("EnableRemoteControl",5)
```

Why are you using 5? Tested with 2 and it seemed to work

```
$User.InvokeSet("EnableRemoteControl",2)
```

Comment: Whether I use 5 or 2 doesn't seem to change anything for me. Write-Host $User.Path will give me the LDAP path however it will not work when utilized in conjunction with invokeset. I am instead given the error ``` Method invocation failed because [System.String] does not contain a method named 'InvokeSet'. ```

Comment: [System.String]??? sounds like that variable is no longer a "DirectoryEntry". Try declaring the variable like this instead ```[ADSI]$LdapUser = "LDAP://" + (Get-ADUser $username).distinguishedName```, then don't specify the class [ADSI] again.

Comment: Check this online resource, they use $user.psbase.invokeSet (https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-edit-terminal-server-profiles-for-users-in-active-directory/)